# I can't easily remote desktop to another computer

Tags: remote-desktop

Everytime I do so I got this message:

The system administrator has restricted the types of logon (network or interactive) that you may use

[image]

It happens on my second rig.

I think this is how I can reproduce the problem.

Login as my self
Create another user that doesn't have microsoft account (local account).
Name it admin, make it admin.
Now this problem doesn't exist

Here is how to recreate the problem

Delete the original self account in the computer

Now that admin is the only account.

Now I have this problem.

I can create admin2 to the computer. It will have the same problem.

The problem go away if I do not remember my credential but have to enter password every time.

I think whatever causing it must be bulls****

Why?

Because I simply delete credential and I can remote again just fine. I can't just save credential and use the same shortcut again.

Only happen in from 1 computer to another.

I temporarily "fixed" the problem by simply not storing credentials. So I got to insert password everytime I remote to that computer.

Remoting to that same computer from other computer is fine. I can remote to another computer too from my current computer.

It happened first when the remote user is still a local. However, the problem remain when the remote user is changed to administrator.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What's the OS on the system you're trying to reach?  I know that saving credentials simply doesn't work on WinXP.

Comment: both are windows 10

Comment: Have you contacted your system administrator for [assistance](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2214046d-6d8a-4254-9586-014c07845c29/remote-desktop-not-allowed-between-two-windows-81-pro-pcs?forum=w8itpronetworking)?  You will need to get a system administrator involved because, unless you are a system administrator, you won't be able to get us the information (or change the required polcies) required to solve this problem.  Vulgar language, even masked, isn't acceptable.

Comment: I am my system administrator of both computer.Yes, I've been calling my self.

Comment: Can you tell us what the RD settings on the target PC are?

Comment: On the target? Allow remote connection. In fact, I do not have this problem as long as one original microsoft account is one of the administrator. It used to work. In fact, my employee computer can remote without this issue either.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what's going on. It's just happen that I have created a flashdisk to install windows 10 on many machines.

Well, I reinstall windows.